# Can't access to a js file whith data-action in my phtml file, zend 2

Tags: zend-framework2, action, php

I'm developping a new application using ZF2. The problem is in my `.phtml` file. I have a `<div>` contains a `data-action` for a js files, but the problem is that when I click nothing happens.

I do not know what the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <?php
        echo $this->headLink(array('rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'type' =>    'image/vnd.microsoft.icon', 'href' => $this->basePath() . '/img/favicon.ico'))
        //<!-- Theme CSS -->
            ->prependStylesheet('/css/font.css')
            ->prependStylesheet('/css/picedit.css')
            ->prependStylesheet('/dist/css/picedit.min.css')
            ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/frontend/css/picedit.min.css')
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="testform" action="out.php" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="picedit_action_btns active">
                <div class="picedit_control ico-picedit-picture" data-action="load_image">      </div>
                <div class="picedit_control ico-picedit-camera" data-action="camera_open">   </div>
                <div class="center">or copy/paste image here</div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <script src="<?php echo $this->basePath(); ?>/dist/js/picedit.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo $this->basePath(); ?>/dist/js/picedit.min.js">  </script>
        <script src="<?php echo $this->basePath(); ?>/dist/js/jquery.min.js">  </script>
        <script src="<?php echo $this->basePath(); ?>http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('.picedit_box').picEdit({
                    imageUpdated: function (img) {},
                    formSubmitted: function () {},
                    redirectUrl: false,
                    defaultImage: false
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help please ?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to add scripts like this:

```
<?php 
echo $this->headScript()->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/some_file.js')
                        ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/another_file.js');
```

It is very similar to how you added the stylesheets.

You can check [official ZF2 documentation on this here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.head-script.html#basic-usage).

Please try this and please come back if it still doesn't work after that.